# How to refresh the size of a RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have this `RelativeLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to make textView2 `GONE` by clicking on a `Button`. I want to get the height of the `RelativeLayout` before, and after that.

I wrote this code, to do that:

```
Boolean shown = true;
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
final TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
final RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int saveHeight = rl.getHeight();
            if(shown) {
                tv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else {
                tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            shown = !shown;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), saveHeight + " " + rl.getHeight(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

My problem is that I always get the old size when I call `rl.getHeight`.

I have already tried to use:

```
rl.requestLayout();
rl.invalidate();
rl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
rl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

My question is: how do I refresh the `RelativeLayout`, so that the **height** is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use ViewTreeObserver. You could use it to listen to layout changes.

```
final RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout )findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
 ViewTreeObserver vto=.getViewTreeObserver();
 vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // This will always update height
        relHeight=rl.getHeight();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the visibility is enough. However, the layout is not measured and laid out synchronously. Instead just a "layout request" message is posted on the UI thread message queue. One way to retrieve the new size is to `post()` your own runnable there that retrieves the new size, e.g.

```
final int saveHeight = ...;
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
view.post(new Runnable() {
  @Override public void run() {
     int newHeight = ...;
  }
});
```